# Dropdownlist Selected value in postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 dropdownlists(ddl1,ddl2) and a gridview with 2 dropdown lists(gddl1,gddl2). On `SelectedIndexChanged` event of ddl1 am changing `SelectedIndex` of gddl1 in postback.

My problem is
ddl1.databind() occurs at a **button's click event**. So once selectedindex of ddl1 changes, the selected value losts and returns back to initial value.

I cant use `!IsPostback` because am binding ddl1 on button click.
How can I retain ddl1 and ddl2 selected index.?

```
protected void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ddlLocation.SelectedIndex > -1) {
        empDS = ws_service.GetEmpList(ddlLocation.SelectedValue, ((ddlDept.SelectedValue == "All") ? "" : ddlDept.SelectedValue), ((ddlGrade.SelectedValue == "All") ? "" : ddlGrade.SelectedValue));
        appraiserDS = ws_service.GetAppList();
        grdDetails.DataSource = empDS.Tables[ 0 ].DefaultView;
        grdDetails.DataBind();

        ddlAppraiserAll.DataSource = appraiserDS.Tables[ 0 ].DefaultView;
        ddlAppraiserAll.DataTextField = "APPRAISER_NAME";
        ddlAppraiserAll.DataValueField = "APPRAISER_ID";
        ddlAppraiserAll.DataBind();
    }
}


protected void ddlAppraiserAll_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow gvRow in grdDetails.Rows) {
        Control ctrl = gvRow.FindControl("ddlAppraiserId");
        DropDownList ddl = ctrl as DropDownList;
        if(ddl != null)
            ddl.SelectedIndex = ddlAppraiserAll.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ itzArun: try to use update panel with asynchronous post back

Comment: @Rocky But am using 2.0 framework. So I cant use update panel. Is it necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is synchronization and its where you get it and where you bind it, but you can also direct get the value using the `Request.Form`.

```
Request.Form[DropDownListID.UniqueID]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood your problem since it's difficult to see what's `ddl1`, `ddl2`, `gddl1` and so on and when each event is handled.

But my guess is:

- DataBind your GridView in `btnProceed_Click`
- Bind the two DropDownLists of the GridView only in [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Then your "GridView-DropDownLists" are always up-to-date according to the selected value of `ddl1`

Comment: `ddlAppraiserAll` is outside of gridview. Am binding that on `btnProceed_Click` and also binding Gridview `grdDetails`. Gridview has 2 dropdownlists (`ddlAppraiserId,ddlReviewerId`). Binding these dropdownlists in `RowDataBound` event.
I want to change the selectedindex of gridview's dropdown `ddlAppraiserId` by changing `ddlAppraiserAll`.
Selected value of `ddlAppraiserId` are up-to-date correctly but `SelectedIndex` of `ddlAppraiserAll` not retaining after postback.

Comment: @itzArun: We are talking at cross purposes. If i understand you correctly you need to set `ddlAppraiserId` according to the SelectedValue of `ddlAppraiserAll`, aren't you? Then my advice was to take this into account in RowDataBound on binding `ddlAppraiserId`. And when the GridView is bound after `ddlAppraiserAll`'s SelectedIndex changed, `ddlAppraiserId` will automatically have the correct items. **Finally**: Are you binding ddlAppraiserAll in page_load also on postbacks? You should only bind it `if(!IsPostBack)` **and** in `btnProceed_Click`. Then it will retain its value.

Answer (score 0):

you can retain ddl1 and ddl2 selected index by storing them in viewstate as properties.

```
        private string ddlSelectedIndex
    {
        set { ViewState["SelectedIndex"] = value; }
        get { return ViewState["SelectedIndex"] == null ? string.Empty : ViewState["SelectedIndex"].ToString(); }
    }
```

The above property is in string, you can create an int property in similar way or use the same and cast index as string. Your selected index will be retained on subsequent postbacks.